# Restrict/Force only some view controllers to specific orientations when using UITabBarController and/or UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, landscape-portrait

I searched the web high and low, but couldn't find a definitive answer on this. What's the best way to have only one `UIViewController` support landscape mode when it's embedded in a `UINavigationController`, which itself is part of a `UITabBarController`?

Most solutions, [like this one](http://www.sebastianborggrewe.de/only-make-one-single-view-controller-rotate/), suggest *overriding*

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
```

in the `AppDelegate`. This works somewhat, but when returning from the only `ViewController` which supports landscape mode, all the other (non-landscape ViewControllers) will be in landscape orientation as well. They don't keep their portrait orientation.

I've seen apps getting this right, so I know that it must be possible somehow. For instance, movie player apps are often portrait-only, but the actual movie player view is presented modally in forced-landscape mode. Upon dismissing the modal viewcontroller, the underlying viewcontroller is still correctly in portrait orientation,

Any hints?

Comment: try these links http://www.fantageek.com/1085/force-only-one-view-controller-to-be-landscape/, http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-orientations-landscape-orientation-one-view-controller/

Comment: Thanks! [This one](http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-orientations-landscape-orientation-one-view-controller/) contains the interesting part "A small problem with modal controllers" which seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my conclusion after a **lot** of research:

First, I tried implementing

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window;
```

in the AppDelegate as described [here](http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-orientations-landscape-orientation-one-view-controller/), which worked for most cases. But apart from feeling quite "hacky", there was one serious gotcha: The workaround for modally displayed view controllers (see section "A small problem with modal controllers") breaks down when, for instance, displaying an `AVPlayerViewController` because it implements its own dismiss method and you can't hook into it to set `self.isPresented` (unfortunately, `viewWillDisappear:` is too late).

So I went with the alternative approach of using subclasses for `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` which feels much cleaner and only slightly more verbose:

### CustomNavigationController

#### CustomNavigationController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end
```

#### CustomNavigationController.m

```
#import "CustomNavigationController.h"

@implementation CustomNavigationController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

@end
```

### CustomTabBarController

#### CustomTabBarController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTabBarController : UITabBarController

@end
```

#### CustomTabBarController.m

```
#import "CustomTabBarController.h"

@implementation CustomTabBarController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.selectedViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

@end
```

After that it's just a matter of adding the following code to your `UIViewControllers`:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    // Presents the `UIViewController` in landscape orientation when it is first displayed 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    // Allows all other orientations (except upside-down)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Now you may decide the preferred and supported orientations on a per-view-controller-basis. Note that I didn't implement `shouldAutorotate` in my view controllers because it defaults to YES, which is what you want if your view controllers should be forced to a certain orientation (yes, they should autorotate to the only supported orientation).

The call chain goes something like this:

- The `CustomTabBarController`, being the window's `rootViewController`, is asked for supported/preferred orientations
- The `CustomTabBarController` in turn asks its `selectedViewController` (view controller of the currently selected tab), which happens to be my `CustomNavigationController`
- The `CustomNavigationController` asks the embedded `topViewController`, which is finally the actual `UIViewController` implementing the methods above

You still need to allow all device orientations in your build target. And of course, you need to update your storyboards/xibs/classes to use these subclasses instead of the standard `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController` classes.

The only downside to this approach is that, at least in my case, I had to add these methods to *all* of my view controllers to make most view controllers portrait-only and some landscape-capable. But IMHO it's definitely worth it!

Answer (score 0):

You should write the above code to the `UINavigationController` subclass. You should define your application orientation and separate your view controller orientation using if statements.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    if ([[self.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]] ) {

        return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
    }

    return NO;

}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    if ([[self.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {

        return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {


    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

}
```